# The voice of the people - Vox Populi

Tags: bug

So I seem to have run into a speed bump with this badge.

I've hit my daily limit of 40.

[image: Daily limit reached]

Yet the `Vox Populi` badge refuses to shower me in gold... err... silver ;-)

[image: Vox Populi]

What gives? :-)

Comment: It's actually bronze...  but still ;-)

Comment: The question looks familiar! Hoperfect it was gonna be an up vote and a down vote:p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You now get an extra 10 votes a day but these can only be used on
>   questions. So to get the Vox populi badge you will have to upvote at
>   least 10 questions in addition to using the "normal" 30 votes.

[Accepted answer to the question What's the difference between Suffrage and Vox populi badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90480/180230)